# $f\in C^{3}[0,+\infty),f,f',f''>0,f'''\leq0.$How to prove $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{ff''}{f'^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f\in C^{3}[0,+\infty)$ and $f,f',f''>0,f'''\leq0.$ I want to prove
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{ff''}{f'^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{2}.$$
I have proved that
$$\frac{f'}{f''}\geq\frac{x}{2},\frac{f}{f'}\geq\frac{x}{4}.$$
But this two inequalities seem no help to this problem (the second is opposite.)
I think some other functions should be constructed,but I cannot construct them.Any help will be thanked.

Answer (score 1):

If the inequalities you proved are correct,then:

$$-\frac{f}{f'} \leq -\frac{x}{4}$$ $$\frac{f''}{f'} \leq \frac{2}{x}$$

So $-\frac{ff''}{f'f'} \leq -\frac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow \liminf_{x \to +\infty}(-\frac{ff''}{f'f'}) \leq -\frac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow \limsup_{x \to +\infty}\frac{ff''}{f'f'} \geq \frac{1}{2}$